# Error : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected in persp {fields}

Tags: r, plot, geospatial

I have 500 points in space with `lat`, `lng` as :

```
lng=runif(100,1,4)
lat=runif(100,40,40.1)
```

Let's say that we have there (density) as

```
z=rnorm(1000)
```

I've tried to plot 3d surface using `persp`

```
persp(lng,lat,z)
```

But I have this error :

```
Error : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
```

I sorted `x` and `y` using

```
data=data.frame(lng,lat)
data=data[ order(data[,1],data[,2]), ]
```

And I tried again

```
persp(data[,1],data[,2],z)
```

But I still have the same problem.

How can I do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: x and y should be in ascending order, see the examples here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/persp.html .

Comment: that is both `x` and `y` need to be ordered. Your ordering command only orders `x`.

Comment: also `z` is expected to be a `matrix` of dimension (`lenght(x)`, `lenght(y))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the argument `z` and the ordering of both `x` and `y`. As shadow mentions in the comments this needs to be a matrix of `dim(z) = length(x) x length(y)` in this case `100x100`. And apparently x and y need to be **both** ordered at the same time exactly as shadow mentions above which is seen in the source code of `persp.default` as.well:

```
if (any(diff(x) <= 0) || any(diff(y) <= 0)) #both need to be ordered
        stop("increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected")
```

So the following works:

```
lng=runif(100,1,4)
lat=runif(100,40,40.1)
z=matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100,nrow=100) #use the correct z as matrix
data=data.frame(lng,lat)
data=data[ order(data[,1],data[,2]), ]   #just order lng as you do 
data$lat <- sort(data$lat)               #you need to sort lat too

persp(data[,1] ,data[,2], z)
```

And this works now.

[image]

**Edit**

I think what you really want to do is to have you lan/lng coordinates in z and plot them. The `z` argument needs to carry the coordinates. the x and y arguments just carry the values of the x and y axes respectively. You can use the default x and y argumens (i.e. leave them blank) or just sort lan and lng separately to provide the real values. So, the solution you are looking for is:

```
lng=runif(100,1,4)
lat=runif(100,40,40.1)
z= as.matrix(data.frame(lng=lng,lat=lat))
z=matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100,nrow=100) #z contains lan and lng

#plot z with default x and y values (or use sorted lng and lat instead)
persp( z = z)
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you , But when you do : data$lat <- sort(data$lat)  , this could change your data.

Comment: Yes I know it changes the order of the pairs (the x,y co-ordinates). I think the way you need to use this function is to have your x, y co-ordinates in the z matrix. x and y values are only the corresponding values of the x and y axes. Try having x and y as the default values i.e. do not use those and use z as the lng, lan coordinates. I think this is what you need.