# R: plot3d - How to sort x and y variables while keeping z associated with the correct pair?

Tags: r, rgl, plot3d

I'm attempting to plot a surface in 3 dimensions using `plot3D` but I'm running into problems. I'm hoping you guys could help or at least point me in the right direction. I'm open to using a different package if that's the solution.

I'm reading in a tab-delimited text file with a couple of dozen columns, each is it's own variable, and each row is a single observation (I hope that makes sense).

Let's say `r_NH4` is what I want to map to the x axis, `r_NO3` is y, `removal_N` is `z`.

`plot3D`requires x and y to be monotonically increasing if your input is a matrix. The structure of my data, and the size, make it difficult to sort both increasing (at least I haven't been able to figure out how to do it). Reading the man page I learned that lists can be used to input `x`, `y`, `z` all at once (with no reference to order).

I create a list for plot3d to interpret:

```
list.r_conc<-list(x=r_NH4,y=r_NO3,z=removal_N,3)
```

And I try to plot in `plot3d`.

```
library(plot3D)
plot3d(list.r_conc,
    xlab="x",
    ylab="y",
    zlab="z",
    xlim=c(0,40),
    ylim=c(0,40)
    )
```

The result creates an `rgl` object that plots each of the points as a scatter plot, not as a surface.

Is there a way to turn this into a surface by adding an argument to the `plot3D` command?

Is the fact that my data is discrete and/or unordered preventing the surface from being plotted?

Searching for a solution led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318300/error-increasing-x-and-y-values-expected-in-persp-fields) question. Trying to follow the solution I tried the following script:

```
z=as.matrix(data.frame(r_NH4,r_NO3))
z=matrix(removal_N,ncol=length(r_NH4),nrow=(r_NO3))
persp3d(z=z)
```

The output was a jumbled mess of planes and the axis for `r_NH4` and `r_NO3` were odd/not consistent with the input (but at least it's not creating a scatterplot!).

Is there a way to sort by both `x` and `y` variables while keeping `z` associated with the correct coordinates?

Is plot3D even capable of plotting a surface using discrete values (instead of a model or function)?

---

```
r_NH4    r_NO3    removal_N
2.220    16.816     1.609
1.734    13.280     4.262
0.000    21.586    -3.240
25.166    3.111     3.479
25.652    2.887     4.708
31.751    3.021    -4.899
17.042    4.868     3.118
23.259   15.917     2.968
23.560   15.773     3.250
24.973   14.533     0.848
25.452   13.973     2.880
21.599   11.528    -4.727
25.243   13.193     0.950
25.049   13.763    -1.134
25.434   14.550     2.152
26.499   15.446     0.606
25.661   15.207     2.449
19.422   10.645     2.350
```

Comment: Please provide a small subset of your data to make it reproducible.

Comment: @nicola Added! I apologize for not including that in the original post.